# Bluetooth does not detect any devices [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

My bluetooth does not detect any devices - phones, other laptops, bluetooth speaker, keyboards, etc.

It just keeps searching and searching.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3DCm.png)

I am very new to Linux, so I would really appreciate some help on this. Please tell me what additional information you guys need so that you can help me.

Output of: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:66a5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:2012 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Kristiyan

Comment: You can try by installing 'blueman'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, I added the output to my question.

Comment: Your BT device is `04ca:2012 Lite-On Technology Corp. `

Comment: @Pilot6, I downloaded Broadcom Windows 8 driver from the first link that is provided but I could not find `bcbtums-win8x86-brcm.inf` file. Instead I only found: `bcbtumsLD-win7x64.inf` and `bcbtums-win8x64-brcm.inf`

However I opened `bcbtums-win8x64-brcm.inf` and found the RAMUSB21D7 section and the name of the firmware file is: BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0229.hex 

However I do not know how to do this:
4. Now extract that firmware from the same cab file.

Would you please help?

Comment: Why do you search for 21d7 device if yours is 2012? You can extract a file by dragging it out by a mouse.

Comment: @Pilot6, when I entered `~/hex2hcd/hex2hcd ~/BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0229.hex~/BCM43142A0-0a5c-2012.hcd` the following message comes in the terminal: **Usage: /home/kriss/hex2hcd/hex2hcd <input hex file> <output file>**

Am I doing it right? I feel that something is wrong .. :(

Comment: There should be a space between the input and output file paths. And for Ubuntu 16.04 the output file name should be `BCM.hcd`.

Comment: @Pilot6, first, I cannot find this file `bcbtums-win8x86-brcm.inf`. I downloaded the file  from here: <http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Broadcom/ASUS-X99-DELUXE-Broadcom-Bluetooth-Driver-6515800-12009860.shtml>
Second, when I try to find RAMUSB2012 I find nothing.  I could only find the numbers of my BT device **04ca** but that's it. 

Obviously that other explanation does not work for my case or I am doing it all wrong. 

I would appreciate some more help. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Name of the inf file can differ. If the `04ca:2012` firmware is not there, then you need to find another Windows driver for this adapter.