# How to install firmware for my 04ca:2012 Broadcom bluetooth adapter

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, broadcom

My original question was this one: [Bluetooth does not detect any devices [Ubuntu 16.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863605/bluetooth-does-not-detect-any-devices-ubuntu-16-04)

but it was marked as a duplicate however I could not find the solution even here: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

So, how can I fix this problem: "Bluetooth does not detect any devices. It just keeps searching and searching."

[image: Here's a screenshot]

It was recommended to me that I find another Windows driver for this adapter, which I do not know how to do.

[Edit] Output of: `dmesg | grep -i blue; rfkill list`

```
[   15.098083] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   15.098120] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.098128] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.098133] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.098153] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.248294] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   25.241033] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   25.246820] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   25.263214] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   25.263227] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   26.216477] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0339
[   26.232575] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 USB
[   26.960425] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.960430] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.960438] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you converted the correct firmware file? If you are sure that it is a kernel bug. The but nay be fixed in newer kernels, or may not.

Comment: I  did the following: Pasted this in terminal: ~/hex2hcd/hex2hcd ~/BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0311.0339.hex ~/BCM.hcd and then many many many lines appeared (I cannot copy them here, it's just too many lines) but it started with `15, :020000040021D9

bump addr to 0x00210000`

and then I got a BCM.hcd file in my home folder. The I typed this in the terminal: `sudo cp ~/BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm` and the BCM file was copied in the brcm folder. Did I make a mistake somewhere along the way?

Comment: All looks correct. Then it is a bug with this adapter. There were some fixes in newer kernels. You can try kernel 4.8 from Ubuntu mainline ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6, I turned the laptop off and on and the Bluetooth works!!! However, when I connect it to my Bluetooth loudspeaker I get no sound :( I checked the sound settings and it says that I am connected with Headset SBL 4.1 A1. (I've tested the loudspeaker with a cable and it works) any idea how I can fix that or am I going offtopic .. :)

Comment: The sound issue is another question. It can be solved, but I have no idea how.

Comment: @Pilot6,  Anyway, thank you very much for helping me solve this issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new device. Download [this driver](http://drivers.drp.su/Bluetooth/Broadcom/FORCED/8110x64/12.0.1.1011/Broadcom-FORCED-8110x64-12.0.1.1011-drp.exe)

Open it with Archive Manager, then extract folder

```
drivers/DP_Bluetooth_16123/Broadcom/FORCED/8110x64/12.0.1.1011
```

There you will see `bcbtums.inf` file and firmware `hex` files.

The firmware for your `04ca:2012` adapter is `BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0311.0339.hex`.

Convert it to `BCM.hcd` using `hex2hcd` and copy it to `/lib/firmware/brcm`.

Generally speaking you can find Windows drivers for new BT adapters by internet search. In your case I found this driver by `vid_04ca&pid_2012`.

Comment: Okay, I did as you told me to and when I try to copy the BCM.hcd file to `/lib/firmware/brcm` I get the following message: **Permission denied**. I cannot either move or copy this file to the brcm folder. Obviously I have no permission to do that. How can I copy it to the brcm folder?

Comment: Read the http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu answer carefully. There is a command to copy the file with `sudo`.

Comment: Okay, I successfully copied the BCM.hcd file and turned off and on the laptop. Now I have another problem, the Bluetooth cannot be turned on, see the screenshot  It says "bluetooth is disabled". When I press the on/off button, the "on" is highlighted but when I close the window and open it again the Bluetooth is "off". And there is a short message below "Bluetooth is disabled"... How do I fix this now ..?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue; rfkill list` command.